# How would i loop though a file to build a table PHP

Tags: php, file, loops

I need to loop through a file and generate a table with the information( names, phone numbers, emails) but i can seem to get it. This is my PHP so far:

```
<?php
$sortedArr = array();
$file = file("files/info.txt");
foreach($file as $v){
    $tempArr = explode(",",$v);
    $tempArr[1] = substr($tempArr[1],0,-1);
    $str = "$tempArr[1], $tempArr[0]";
    array_push($sortedArr,$str);
}

$arrLen = count ($sortedArr);
    $rowLen = count ($sortedArr[0]);
    $tbl = "<table border= '1'>";


 $tbl .= "<tr>";
 for ($i=0;$i<$arrLen;$i++)
 {
 $tbl .= "</tr>";
  for ($l=0;$l<$rowLen;$l++)
   {
   $tbl .= "<td>" . $arr[$i][$l] . "</td>";
   } 
}
 $tbl .= "</tr>";

$tbl .= "</table>";
?>
```

I thought i could put everything into the $sortedArr and then loop through that, but i haven't had much luck with it. Thanks for the help in advance.

Here is a sample of the file/info.

```
tom,jones,5236895214,kjsdlfkjslfkj@ldjlf
jared,smith,2351547809,blahlbahlbah
john,doe,8745125489,dsjfksjfkjhsdkj
tom,atkins,5214523658,jhdfjashdfkjhsdkfj
```

Comment: Where did you define `$arr`? You have `$sortedArr`, but no `$arr` which is used in the inner incremental `for` loop.

Comment: Always when developing code, turn up error reporting and display errors on screen. You'll likely be clued in by uninitialized variables when PHP complains... `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yeah, that would help a little if i labeled everything right. I cant believe i didnt notice that. I switched it to $sortedArr, now im only getting the first letter of the first entry.

Comment: Can you also post a small sample of the contents of `info.txt`? It would help to see some context for what the `substr()` call is doing.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I put a sample of the file. Thanks for helping me with this.

Comment: Wait a minute - are you trying to get all the columns as output or only the names?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski All the columns. I need all the information.

Comment: Ok, my updated code below handles that. If you didn't really want the first & last names joined in one column like your code implied, you can skip most of the body of the first loop; just explode and stick it straight onto `$sortedArr`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thank you so much! I actually needed each name in its own column, alphabatized by last name, but i can do that. Thanks again for your help! And for letting me know about foreach() instead of for().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first thing's first. In PHP, it is almost never the right course of action to use an incremental `for ()` loop and keep track of `$i`. Simple iteration is best done with `foreach ()` loops. By switching to `foreach`, you'll eliminate the need for all the `count()` accounting, `$i, $l`.

[Here's the whole thing in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ikZTLV)

```
//Starting from the beginning:
$sortedArr = array();
$file = file("files/info.txt");
foreach($file as $v){
    $tempArr = explode(",",$v);

    // Get the first and second values
    // Not sure what the substr() was for
    // since it would remove the last letter of the lastname...
    // Let's omit that.
    $str = $tempArr[0] . ' ' . $tempArr[1];

    // Looks like you want to join the names 0,1
    // and use the rest as they are...

    // The joined string back into the first index
    $tempArr[0] = $str;
    // and get rid of the second since it's joined with the first
    unset($tempArr[1]);

    // Append the array onto your big:
    array_push($sortedArr, $tempArr);
}

// Now open your table, then use 2 foreach
// loops to build the rows and columns, opening and
// closing the <tr> inside each iteration of the outer loop.
$tbl = "<table border='1'>";

// Outer loop is rows
foreach ($sortedArr as $row) {
   // Start a row, close it later
   $tbl .= '<tr>';

   // Inner loop is columns
   foreach ($row as $col) {
      $tbl .= '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($col) . '</td>';
   }
   $tbl .= '</tr>';
}
// Close your table
$tbl .= '</table>';
```